# How to instantiate class directly in namespace?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Well... this is what i want to do. I have a class library project into my solution. Into it i have a class.

I want that class to be instantiated as soon as the solution starts. So it can be accesible from the other projects in the solution like this:

```
Namespace.InstanceOfTheForm.Property
```

Is there any way to do that? or something close to that?

Any ideas? Thanks for helping

EDIT: I previously posted some way around i found but didn't actually worked... so i still have no way around this.

EDIT2: What i was trying to do is to get an instance of an object shared between all the projects of my solution. Diggin a little more, i realised that i should implement some kind of memory sharing between processes right?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for a static class, or in vb.net terms, a shared class.  You don't instantiate it directly, but there is a `Shared Sub New()` you can use that will get called the first time your class is referenced.

**Update:**

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but here is an example of a shared class:

```
Namespace MyNameSpace
  Public Class Test
    Private Shared _TestName As String = String.Empty

    Shared Sub New()
      _TestName = "Instant Name"
    End Sub

    Shared Property TestName As String
      Get
        Return _TestName
      End Get
      Set(value As String)
        _TestName = value
      End Set
    End Property
 End Class

End Namespace
```

And then you just call it from anywhere:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  MessageBox.Show(MyNameSpace.Test.TestName)
  MyNameSpace.test.TestName = "Changed Name"
  MessageBox.Show(MyNameSpace.Test.TestName)
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain the concept deeply? How should i use this Shared Class aproach? Thanks

Comment: The actual VB way to make a static class is `Module`.  Also in this case, there is no reason (other than demonstration purposes perhaps) to have a shared constructor, since the fields could all be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

If this will be the only instance of the class and you don't inherit from anything else, you can use a Module instead.

But, from the name, it sounds like you want a Form. In that case, all forms in VB.Net already have a default instance you can use. No need to create a separate instance at all. I normally advise against using these, though, because it leads to poor practices later on.